# ReferenceERROR: window is not defined - where is the Window this error is referring to?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react 16.3.2 on Ubuntu and am wanting to integrate my new react application with [this software](https://github.com/superfly/fly).

I have posted the code below, but have also made a github repository for this, in case you wanted to look at that and scope out the code more:

[Github Repo](https://github.com/r-wells/fly-react-app)

My webpack.fly.config.js file:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const bundlePath = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
query: { presets: ['react']}
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: { extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx'] },
  output: {
    publicPath: bundlePath,
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname,'public'),
    port: 3000,
    publicPath: "http://localhost:3000/dist"
  },
  plugins: [ new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin() ]
};
```

Which I don't think is the issue, because when I run `fly server` the server begins to run, but when I go to refresh my **localhost** webpage, I get the error below:

> ReferenceError: window is not defined
>       at module.exports (bundle.js:5:41)
>       at bundle.js:728:10
>       at ()
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@fly/fly/lib/default_context_store.js:47:30

My index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I've also tried the following for an index.js file:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

fly.http.respondWith(function(request){
    ReactDOM.render(
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    ) };
```

But still get the same issue

And my index.html:

```
<!-- sourced from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/master/static/html/single-file-example.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>React Starter</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <script src="../dist/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

React and Webpack are both still pretty new to me, so I'm not even sure what this error is or what it means.

Could someone shed some light here and point me in the right direction?

Comment: Fly.js runs server-side code, not client-side code.

Comment: Thanks, how does that relate to this and the problem this is running into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in comment - Fly.js runs server-side code, not client-side code.

That means any code that will try to use `window` will fail because the `window` is only defined in the browser - when running on Node `window` will be undefined.

Comment: Okay thank you, but I’m not seeing where my code is trying to use Window

Comment: Not your code but libraries you use. Maybe [this](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/demystifying-reacts-server-side-render-de335d408fe4) will help.

Comment: Is there a simple way to only render `window` if it is in the browser?

Comment: Actually better question - does this mean that trying to run this code locally is a nonworking idea but deploying it to the servers would work? I read the article, that was very helpful, thank you.

Comment: why do you need fly.js? Just build your app with `npm run build` and host your static files somewhere.

Comment: I want to host it on fly so it is pre-rendered. I'm still pretty new with React so thanks for your time and patience explaining all of this.